# How to show users that do and dont exist in a table from a list, SQL

Tags: sql

So I have a table with thousands of user records. I want to look up a list of users from this table. I want to be shown the list of users that were found and users that had no record in this table

So far my query is as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
u.[username],
u.[fullName],
u.[EmailAddress],
u.[address],
u.[number]
FROM [v_Users] u
WHERE u.[fullName] IN 
('John smith', 'Bob dylan', 'Jack smith', 'Ashley cooper', 'test12', 'jane112')
```

Just wanted to know, whats the smartest way to display values for the names found and to also display the names not found ('test12', 'jane112')

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.[username],
                u.[fullName],
                u.[EmailAddress],
                u.[address],
                u.[number],
                case when u.[fullName] IN ('John smith', 'Bob dylan', 'Jack smith', 'Ashley cooper', 'test12', 'jane112') 
                     then 'found' 
                     else 'not found' 
                end as search_result
FROM [v_Users] u
```